# Java mail api is not working in final release of android app?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have made app which uses java mail api to send mail to me when customer orders something. Its working fine until i release the app. In short still working fine with.apk file. But when i uploaded it on google play console with.aab file its not working giving error as follow. "Errorb5.g :smtp" What would be the cause for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.